# File Group Restore Failed in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, restore, database-backups

I am trying to restore a database using File Groups Concept in SQL Server.

I am trying to take a backup from  `"FGTest_STG"` DB and Restore it in `"FGTest_PROD"` DB.Both the Database Exists in `SQL Server`.

Restore Query:

```
RESTORE DATABASE FGTest_Prod
        FILEGROUP = 'Primary'
        FROM DISK = 'E:\SQLDATA\FGTest_Stg_2014.06.10.165900.bak'
        WITH MOVE 'FGTest_Stg' TO 'E:\Databases\FGTest_Prod_2014_06_10_171410.mdf'
        ,MOVE 'FGTest_Stg_log' TO 'E:\DBLogs\FGTest_Prod_2014_06_10_171410.ldf' ,REPLACE
```

But when I restore i am getting the below error.

```
<code>The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'FGTest_Prod' database.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally</code>
```

Comment: error msg seems self explanatory...